# Storage size in if statement

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

unsigned short int var1;
unsigned int var2;

var2 = 37000;
var1 = 36000;

if(var2 < (100 * var1))
printf("True \n");

return 0;
}
```

In the above code when I do `(100 * var1)` what happens? What's the storage size for that?

Comment: Please explain why you need to know this, so that the answers would be more directional.

Answer (score 2):

It's an `int`. So, most likely 4 bytes depending on your compiler / architecture.

Keep in mind you're not actually storing that value anywhere.

Comment: is it always int or it depends on the variable size it's compared against?

Comment: It will always be an int, provided an int can store that value. If it's bigger than that, you'll get overflow.

Comment: @Kitcha it depends on what you are comparing. The intermediate expression takes the size of data type needing the largest amount of bytes to store. For your case, it will always be int and overflow will occur if intermediate result cannot be stored.

Answer (score 0):

storage size is `sizeof (unsigned int)`; the memory required to store an `unsigned int` is not dependent on what value you assign it.

In fact, you have not made any assignments. regardless, you still have a memory location that is precisely `sizeof(unsigned long)` (whether you use it or not :)

Answer (score 0):

`var1` is a `short` (the `unsigned` doesn't change storage size), normally 2 bytes (but not guaranteed to be all systems). The literal `100` is an `int`, usually 4 bytes but again, not guaranteed. The product of a short and an int is an int, so it will use int storage size. You can force the compiler to interpret the literal `100` as a short by appending an 's':

```
(var1 * 100s)
```

or an unsigned short by appending 'us':

```
(var1 * 100us)
```

But this won't change the size of the output as all operations on shorts first involve a conversion to int.

If you want to know how many bytes anything takes up in a program, just use the builtin function/operator `sizeof` to find out:

```
sizeof(var1 * 100); //calculates size of the expression in bytes
```

In your case, the value is temporary anyway and it's storage size shouldn't affect your program.

Comment: Using an `s` suffix won't change anything, because shorts are always converted to ints before doing any operations on them.  So in `(var1 * 100s)` both operands are shorts, but both are converted to ints before the multiply and the result will be an int.